# How to check ImageView tag while clicking

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, tags, uiimage

I have UIImageView displays in the screen have tag value of each. Then when i do long press i'm deleting the images from UIView. But i want  check which image i'm deleting while doing long press. Here ObjectAddedToScreen is the Model view of holding the displaying images.

```
  mmageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,150,150)];


     [mmageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];



     //  [mmageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1]]]]];


     [mmageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1]] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {

     // [loadingViewLbl2 removeFromSuperview];

     }];

     [mmageView setTag:[sender tag]-1];


     object = [[ObjectAddedToScreen alloc] init];
     object.productDescription = [descript_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1];
     object.view = mmageView;
     [self.objectsAddedToScreen addObject:object];

 object.object_sku=[sku_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1];


     [self.view addSubview:mmageView];
```

Long Press delete:

```
-(void)dblongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender{
 CGPoint tapLocation1 = [sender locationInView: self.view];
 for (UIImageView *imageeView1 in self.view.subviews) {
 if (CGRectContainsPoint(imageeView1.frame, tapLocation1)) {

 //    [imageeView1 removeFromSuperview];

 [imageeView1 setHidden:YES];


 }
 }

 }
```

UIImageView_ID store:

```
  const char *sqlInsert = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into product_sku (sku) values ('%@')", object.object_sku] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Hi you are almost done with that. Just inside dblongPress: method add one line inside if condition. NSLog(@"%d", imageeView1.tag)

Comment: As an option, if you attach instance of UILongPressGestureRecognizer to every of your image views, then in method -dblongPress: you will get the required tag via sender.view.tag

Comment: Can you check my edited code. Each image having some id then i'm getting the id, insert to database  object.object_sku=[sku_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1];. How can check the deleting image from store

Comment: @oradyvan: how can i use, sender.view.tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code may look like this:

```
mmageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,150,150)];
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dblongPress:)];
[mmageView addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];

// the rest is like yours:
[mmageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];



 //  [mmageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1]]]]];


 [mmageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1]] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {

 // [loadingViewLbl2 removeFromSuperview];

 }];

 [mmageView setTag:[sender tag]-1];


 object = [[ObjectAddedToScreen alloc] init];
 object.productDescription = [descript_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1];
 object.view = mmageView;
 [self.objectsAddedToScreen addObject:object];

 object.object_sku=[sku_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1];


 [self.view addSubview:mmageView];
```

Then the gesture recognizer handler is:

```
- (void)dblongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    // object SKU is stored in imageView's tag
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)sender.view;
    NSInteger object_sku = sender.view.tag;

    // remove the object from database
    const char *sqlDelete = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete from product_sku where sku = %d", object_sku] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [database executeUpdate:sqlDelete];

    // hide the image view
    imageView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: I have number for sku. So, i'm matching image tag with sku number. So, i used object.object_sku=[sku_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1];. Here how can i check the sku number while deleting the image tag?

Comment: how can i compare mmageView &  object.object_sku values while deleting the image tag?

Comment: You don't have to compare them. In the method -dblongPress: you explicitly obtain the object via your code `object.object_sku=[sku_array objectAtIndex:[sender.view tag]-1];` and you also have imageView as I said above.

Comment: So, you can remove your object from the model and also schedule removing imageView from superview like this: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [imageView removeFromSuperview]; });`

Comment: See i'm removing from this code [imageeView1 setHidden:YES];. but i inserted model view object.object_sku into database. So, when i delete the image i need to delete in database also. How can i pass object.object_sku for delete the image.

Comment: I can re-write the code but I need to know how removing objects is implemented in your code. You said `object_sku` is a number, so there should be a method somewhere like `[model removeObjectBySKU:object_sku]` in your code. Is this correct assumption?

Comment: no...I have 4 field in database like id, name, product_image, sku. I get p_i from database and store to productimg_array. corresponding click i'm getting sku number of p_i. So, i can easily get the present images sku id in the ObjectAddedToScreen and store to database. But if i delete the p_i then how can i get associate sku id of the p_i?

Comment: Well, in this case you have to look up for appropriate instance of your ObjectAddedToScreen in `self.objectsAddedToScreen`, looking for particular SKU you set to the imageView tag. After you found the appropriate object that has the SKU you can execute set of queries removing all the associated data from DB.

Comment: I can able to get and store the database. I don't have clue, how to execute the delete in DB

Comment: You can use DELETE SQL query, see my code of method -dblongPress: for an example.

Comment: That's ok. But my doubt is how to get instance of SKU with p_i delete. Does it simple add this UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)sender.view;
    NSInteger object_sku = sender.view.tag;

Comment: Please help this if you know

Comment: In your code instead of `[mmageView setTag:[sender tag]-1];` do this: `object.object_sku=[sku_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1]; [mmageView setTag:object.object_sku];`

Comment: I used dblongpress: method from answer, but i'm getting last updated value delete only. If i click the 2 images dsiplay in the screen one by one. While deleting i'm getting object_sku value is last updated image value.why?

Comment: @user3743552 It is really hard to advise something without seeing your code. Maybe you could create another answer and show your code so that the community could help you on that?